# Setting up Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am starting with Spring MVC and I am following some tutorials, I am missing something but I can't see what it is.
Here is what I got:
file:pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wearedevelopers</groupId>
  <artifactId>contabills</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

File:contabills-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.wearedevelopers.controllers" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />  
</bean>
```

File: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ContaBills</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-    class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:contabills-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>contabills</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

File: HomeController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("mensagem", "mensagem");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
In console, one of the message is:
[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:contabills' did not find a matching property.

When I request the URL localhost:8080//home/index, I expect the file home.html, wich I have defined, but I got 404.
I believe I am missing something and I can't see what it is.

EDIT:
Also, there is this in console:

INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Comment: The problem is that I am getting 404. The application is not mapping my pages.

Comment: Can someone explain me why down vote for further questions?

Comment: Because you haven't (or hadn't) explained what behavior you expected, why you expected that behavior, and what actual behavior you are getting. What request did you send? For what URL? What part of your Spring MVC application should handle that request? Etc.

Comment: Use Spring Boot, starting with [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io), to skip the outdated boilerplate configuration and get to actual running code.

Comment: Because answers to these questions are becoming boring, here's the short version: you're missing MVC configuration, typically with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. Your servlet configuration is messed up. You declare a Servlet with name `spring-mvc`, but then you declare a servlet mapping for a Servlet named `contabills`. Finally, your servlet is mapped to `*.html`, but you send your request to `.../index`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis still have problems. You see, in my console I got the issue: INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath. Can you tell why my web.xml is not recognized?

Comment: @chrylis I am trying manually to learn how to do. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Your requestmapping should have .html extension according to your servlet mapping in web.xml.

So use .html extension in requestmapping in application. This should work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld(Model model)
    {
```

Comment: Hi, didn't work, besides, there's a template resolver for extensions HTML.

Comment: Please, see my edit in post. I believe my file web.xml is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix two lines.
1st is inside web.xml "spring-mvc" instead of spring-mvc use "contabills" .
2nd is you should always use .html files for RequestMappings because in web.xml you filter all requests html requests to spring dispatcher servlet. 
And i strongly suggest to add a log4j configuration file inside your classpath which is configured to level debug. You can easily trace all steps of your request.

Comment: Done. But I don't even have the chance to log something. It's not getting into the controller.

Answer (score -1):

Your url-pattern is wrong and you're missing the annotation driven statement. By the way, put a `*` after `classpath`. Your files should be like:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath*:contabills-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

**contabills-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.wearedevelopers.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />  
 </bean>
</beans>
```

This should work.

Comment: Yes. See my edit in question. I believe my file web.xml is not recognized.